# Can I book a tatkal ticket in Indian Railways online?

Tags: online-resources, bookings, indian-railways, tatkal

Can I book a tatkal ticket in Indian Railways online ?

Is yes when can it be booked?

Or is it that only premium tatkal tickets can be booked online?

Please help .Its urgent

Answer (score 1):

Tatkal tickets can be booked on IRCTC, the procedure is outlined at https://www.irctc.co.in/eticketing/staticPage/TatkalBooking.html